# 2 ASP.NET Web Apps, same domain, flowing from one to another seamlessly (IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis

I have both a VB.NET web app and a C# web app both running on ASP.NET 4.5. I am in the process of converting everything over to the C# app but for now I need to make it so when the user logs into the C# app they can seamlessly access pages on the VB.NET app.

After reading up on this I figured out that I have to add a MachineKey tag to my web.config for Forms authentication to work across sites.

My main concern is how I will be setting this up in IIS. How would most recommend doing something like this? Would I publish each app separately and have 2 separate websites in IIS with 2 separate app pools? Then how do I make sure they are both using www.mydomain.com/...

Comment: Have you tried setting up identical machine keys and a shared session storage (database or out-of-proc)?

Comment: Yes.. my concern is IIS setup.. As in do I use 1 website with 1 apppool, one directory with 2 folders in it, 1 for each site, etc.. Then do I have to use the Convert to Application function?

Comment: Using several application pools is a good thing if you don't want them to affect each other. One crashing application shouldn't take the other one down. It doesn't matter if you deploy as web sites or web applications, just deploy and try it out.

Comment: I deployed as web applications, created  a new website/appool in IIS and added 2 applications to it pointing them to the appropriate directories. This seems like it is going to work. Just not sure which directory to point the actual IIS Website to since it is technically at its own level now.

Comment: How do I choose which app will be the default? Do I put an index file that redirects to the correct App directory in the Website root or something?

Comment: I would probably put this in 2 separate virtual directories with there own app pools in IIS.  I would then probably setup the base web site to redirect to the application you want to be the default using Http redirects in IIS.  This would allow you to change the default if it becomes necessary with only a configuration change, not a code change.

Comment: Got ya, so it is either that or do a merge of the 2 web.configs. I already seeing this being a pain especially when I have something like <Pages Theme="Default"> on App1 and App2 is different.. Ill have to set the theme in the code instead I guess.